# how to change import form in VS Code when writing code to Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Writing tests in Python using pytest framework

For import classes and functions from subdirectory I write this dicertory at the beginning of the path

My problem is that if i don't write dot at the beginning of the path then code runs fine through VS Code but getting an error if code runs through terminal

If i write dot at the beginning of the path then code runs fine through terminal but getting error if code runs through VS Code

It's very uncomfortable and i want to specidfy single import order for editor and language

I hope somebody know how make this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpoow.jpg)

Comment: [Never post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: What folder do you open as workspace in vscode? How do you run code using the terminal? What are the errors you encountered? Why are you not showing this information? Even the code is just a screenshot.                Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry for not providing more information. I will take it in account in future.
And somehow magically my problem was solved

Comment: Hi ananas1kk, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Please close the post if the problem is solved.

Comment: Please, tell me how to close the post?

Answer (score 0):

You should read ***CWD***. There are no errors in vscode and in the terminal when I don't use dots here.

[image]

Vscode uses the open folder as the workspace, and you are likely to have errors in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Dot in import means that this directory is package. And my directory is package, because it have file "**init**.py"
You can find more information about package in python on internet